# Code error using manipulate

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate

Why this code doesn't work? Can anyone help me?

```
s = {1, 2, 3};
f[x_, s_] := 
 Piecewise[
  Table[{x + i, s[[i]] <= x <= s[[ i + 1]]}, {i, Length[s[1]] - 1}]]
Manipulate[Plot[f[x, s], {x, 0, 3}], {s[[1]], 0, 3}]
```

Comment: Read the error message: {s[[1]], 0, 3} is not a variable specification. Do you mean:Manipulate[Plot[f[x, var], {x, 0, 3}], {var, s}]

Comment: I wanna change the value of s[[i]] with manipulate

Comment: Then "i" is the variable?

Comment: for example for i=1 i have s[[1]]=1 (in this case) but,  using manipulate, i wanna change the value of s[[i]]

Comment: You must do this inside Manipulate. The variable for manipulate must be a simple like e.g. "i" variable, not an array member.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

s = {1, 2, 3};

f[x_] = Piecewise[
  Table[{x + i, s[[i]] <= x <= s[[i + 1]]}, {i, Length[s] - 1}]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

```
Clear[f]

f[x_, s_] := 
 Piecewise[
  Table[{x + i, s[[i]] <= x <= s[[i + 1]]}, {i, Length[s] - 1}]]

Manipulate[
 s = s0 + {1, 2, 3};
 Column[{StringForm["`` = ``", HoldForm[f[x, s]], f[x, s]],
   Plot[f[x, s], {x, s0, s0 + 3},
    PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {0, 9}},
    PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.01],
    ImageSize -> Medium]}],
 {{s0, 0}, 0, 3, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but i wanna change the intervals with manipulate

Comment: Then you need to add something to the definition of `f` that varies and can be manipulated.

Comment: yes, but why my code is wrong?

Comment: Because you gave `s` a fixed value and once defined, the definition of `f` does not change. You would need to make the definition of `s` variable. Alternatively, make `f` dependent on another variable other than `x`

Comment: how can I make s variable?

Answer (score 1):

I'm making some guesses about what you want, but here's a line of thinking...

First off, your function f doesn't really depend on x, and by allowing x to be input as an argument will just open you up to errors and cause confusion. Let's start with this:

```
myPiecewise[intervals_List] :=
  Function[x, 
    Piecewise[
      Table[{x + i, intervals[[i]] <= x < intervals[[i + 1]]}, 
        {i, Length[intervals] - 1}]]]
```

This will output a function that can just take a value, it doesn't require you to guarantee agreement of formal argument names.

Now let's bundle that into a Plot:

```
myPiecewisePlot[intervals_List] := 
  Plot[myPiecewise[intervals][z], 
    {z, intervals[[1]], intervals[[-1]]}]
```

I used z to illustrate that we're no longer dependent on a particular name for the formal argument. Since I've hidden myPiecewise inside myPiecewisePlot, it actually doesn't really matter, but I still like it better. Notice that I'm assuming the plot should start and end with the first and last values of the list provided. That seemed like a reasonable assumption, but I don't know if it's what you want.

Now we're ready for Manipulate:

```
Manipulate[myPiecewisePlot[list], {{list, {0, 1, 2}}}]
```

[image]

You'll have to be careful to enter your value as a list. You may need to add some validation or coercion to this. Anyway, here's an example where I've changed the interval list.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe similar with this result.

```
e = .1;
n = 5;
f[x_, k_] := 
 Which @@ Flatten[Table[{i <= x < i + 1 - e, x + i}, {i, k, n}], 1]
Manipulate[
 Plot[f[x, k], {x, 1, n}, ExclusionsStyle -> Red, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], {k, 1, n - 1, 1}, ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image]